# When I use XPath to extract data it dosen't give any response in the messagebox.show

Tags: c#, html, xpath, google-chrome-devtools, html-agility-pack

Anyone can help me I use Copy Xpath in Google chrome tools developement to get this path :

```html
/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]
```

and I use the path in this code to get data :

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

        doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tablemasterbleue").InnerHtml);

        int i = 2;
        while (doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[1]") != null)
        {
            string Code_de_ligne = "";
            string Numero_de_produit = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[1]").InnerText;
            string Desc_prod = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[5]/span").InnerText;
            string Prix_coutânt = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[7]/span[2]").InnerText;
            string Prix_de_vente = "";
            string Qte = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[6]/input").GetAttributeValue("value", "");

            i++;

            MessageBox.Show(Code_de_ligne + "|" + Numero_de_produit + "|" + Desc_prod + " | " + Prix_coutânt + "|" + Prix_de_vente + "|" + Qte);
        }
```

but it doesn't give any response in the `MessageBox.Show`.

I'm executing *XPath* against this HTML document:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Provincial Tire</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/plugin/favicon.ico">
<link href="/designglobal/inosoft/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">



<link href="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/css/imgpreview.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/css/thickbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
<link href="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/css/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/js/jquery.tablesorter2.min.js"></script> 





<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/js/jquery-thickbox.js"></script>






<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/js/jquery.tooltips.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/js/jquery.imgpreview.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/js/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/jquery/js/swfobject.js"></script>














<script type="text/javascript">




        function envoieRequete(url,id)
        {
            var xhr_object = null;
            var position = id;

               if(window.XMLHttpRequest)  xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
              else
                if (window.ActiveXObject)  xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 

            // On ouvre la requete vers la page désirée
            xhr_object.open("GET", url, true);


            document.getElementById(position).innerHTML = "<center><img src=\"http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/load.gif\" ><\/center>";


            xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( xhr_object.readyState == 4 )
            {

                // j'affiche dans la DIV spécifiées le contenu retourné par le fichier
                document.getElementById(position).innerHTML = xhr_object.responseText;



            }
            }
            // dans le cas du get


            xhr_object.send(null);

        }
 </script>















<script type="text/javascript">


function pausecomp(millis) 
{
var date = new Date();
var curDate = null;

do { curDate = new Date(); } 
while(curDate-date < millis);
} 





        function envoieRequeteWait(url,id)
        {

            pausecomp(5);

            var xhr_object = null;
            var position = id;

               if(window.XMLHttpRequest)  xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
              else
                if (window.ActiveXObject)  xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 

            // On ouvre la requete vers la page désirée
            xhr_object.open("GET", url, true);


            document.getElementById(position).innerHTML = "<center><img src=\"http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/load.gif\" ><\/center>";


            xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( xhr_object.readyState == 4 )
            {

                // j'affiche dans la DIV spécifiées le contenu retourné par le fichier
                document.getElementById(position).innerHTML = xhr_object.responseText;



            }
            }
            // dans le cas du get


            xhr_object.send(null);

        }
 </script>














<script type="text/javascript">

function envoieRequeteSearch(url,id)
        {
 var sid = "2nmia7njlrrc8a9mn5199do5d5";  
            var xhr_object = null;
            var position = id;

               if(window.XMLHttpRequest)  xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
              else
                if (window.ActiveXObject)  xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 

            // On ouvre la requete vers la page désirée
            xhr_object.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr_object.setRequestHeader('Set-Cookie', 'PHPSESSID=' + sid); 

            document.getElementById(position).innerHTML = "<br><br><table align=\"center\" border=\"0\" height=\"250\" width=\"350\" style=\"background-image:url(/designglobal/inosoft/loading_box.png)\"><tr><td align=\"center\"><img src=\"http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/plugins/logoajaxc.gif\" ><br><br><b>Please be patient....<\/b><br><\/td><\/tr><\/table><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";


            xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( xhr_object.readyState == 4 )
            {


                // j'affiche dans la DIV spécifiées le contenu retourné par le fichier
                document.getElementById(position).innerHTML = xhr_object.responseText;















              $(document).ready(function() { 
                  $("table").tablesorter({ 
                      // pass the headers argument and assing a object 
                      headers: { 
                          // assign the secound column (we start counting zero) 
                          9: { 
                              // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                              sorter: false 
                          },                      
                            // assign the third column (we start counting zero) 
                          8: { 
                              // disable it by setting the property sorter to false 
                              sorter: false 
                          } 
                      }

                  }); 
              });




                $(document).ready(function() { 
                /*$('a#first').imgPreview();*/
                $('a#first').imgPreview({
                    imgCSS: { width: 250 }
                }); });





            }
            }
            // dans le cas du get



            xhr_object.send(null);

        }
 </script>
















<script type="text/javascript">

function Requete(url,id)
        {
 var sid = "2nmia7njlrrc8a9mn5199do5d5";  
            var xhr_object = null;
            var position = id;

               if(window.XMLHttpRequest)  xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
              else
                if (window.ActiveXObject)  xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 

            // On ouvre la requete vers la page désirée
            xhr_object.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr_object.setRequestHeader('Set-Cookie', 'PHPSESSID=' + sid); 

            document.getElementById(position).innerHTML = "<img src=\"http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/pbar.gif\" >";


            xhr_object.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( xhr_object.readyState == 4 )
            {


                // j'affiche dans la DIV spécifiées le contenu retourné par le fichier
                document.getElementById(position).innerHTML = xhr_object.responseText;

            }
            }
            // dans le cas du get



            xhr_object.send(null);

        }
 </script>










<script type="text/javascript"> 

function stopRKey(evt) { 
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null); 
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null); 
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;} 
} 

document.onkeypress = stopRKey; 

</script>





<script type="text/javascript">


function toggle(anId)
{
    node = document.getElementById(anId);
    if (node.style.visibility=="hidden")
    {
        // caché vers montrer
        node.style.visibility = "visible";
        node.style.height = "auto";         
    }
    else
    {
        // visible vers cacher
        node.style.visibility = "hidden";
        node.style.height = "0";            
    }
}

</script>





<script type="text/javascript">
        function blocknumber(event) {
        // Compatibilité IE / Firefox
        if(!event&&window.event) {
        event=window.event;
        }
        // IE
        if(event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
        // DOM
        if(event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        }
        }   




function blockletter(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event;
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (!e.shiftKey && !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey &&
    // numbers   
    key >= 48 && key <= 57 ||
    // Numeric keypad
    key >= 96 && key <= 105 ||
    // Backspace and Tab and Enter
    key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 ||
    // Home and End
    key == 35 || key == 36 ||
    // left and right arrows
    key == 37 || key == 39 ||
    // Del and Ins
    key == 46 || key == 45 ||
    // point .
    key == 110) {
        // input is VALID
    }
    else {
        // input is INVALID
        e.returnValue = false;
        if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    }
}

</script>    



<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    theUrl = 'http://www.provincialtire.net/search.html';

    setTimeout("location.replace(theUrl);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//  JavaScript:timedRefresh(1000000); -->
</script>




<script>
function SendInfo(e){

    if(e){
        e = e 
        } else {
        e = window.event
    } 

    if(e.which){ 
    var keycode = e.which
    } else {
    var keycode = e.keyCode 
    }

    if(keycode == 13) { 
         envoieRequeteSearch('modules/searchajax.php?size='+form1.size.value+'&manu='+form1.manu.value+'&desc='+form1.desc.value+'&type='+form1.type.value+'&nostock='+form1.nostock.checked+'&prodno='+form1.prodno.value+'&tri='+form1.tri.value+'&cache='+form1.cache.checked,'conteneur');      

    }

}
</script>

















<script type="text/javascript">if (window != top) top.location.href = location.href;</script>
<noscript>
You do Activate JavaScript on your Brwoser / Vous devez activer le JavaScript de votre navigateur
</noscript>


</head>

<body onload=" ">





<table width="960" border="0" align="center">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td>


    <table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody><tr>
          <td valign="top">


          <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-image:url(http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/plugins/toplogo.jpg)">
            <tbody><tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="392" height="110">

          <div style="position:relative;">

            <div style="position:absolute; bottom:35px; right:5px;">
              <a href="exit-en.html"> <img src="http://www.provincialtire.net/images/error.png" title="Exit"> </a>
            </div>

         </div>                    


                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody></table>

           </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>


      <table width="960" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody><tr>
          <td valign="top" background="/designglobal/inosoft/background.jpg" style="background-repeat:no-repeat;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
















        <div style="position:relative; top:-5px;">

          <table style="background-image:url(/designglobal/inosoft/top_menu_button.jpg)" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" height="45" id="cellule_menu_principal">
            <tbody><tr>


              <td width="50" align="center" class="menu_principal">&nbsp;   </td>

              <td width="96" align="center" class="menu_principal">                 <a style="" href="/">Informations</a>  </td>

              <td width="96" align="center" class="menu_principal">             <a style="" href="promotions-en.html">Promotions</a> </td>

              <td width="96" align="center" class="menu_principal">             <a style="color:#FF0000" href="search-en.html">Search <br> Products</a> </td>

              <td width="96" align="center" class="menu_principal">                 <a style="" href="acount-en.html">Your Account</a> </td>

              <td width="96" align="center" class="menu_principal">             <a style="" href="storage-en.html">Your<br>Storage</a> </td>

              <td width="96" align="center" class="menu_principal">
              &nbsp;              
              </td>

              <td width="96" align="center" class="menu_principal">                  <a style="" href="tracking-en.html">Track Shipments</a> </td>

              <td width="96" align="center" class="menu_principal">             <a style="" href="tools-en.html">Tools</a> </td>

              <td width="80" align="center" class="menu_principal"><a href="modules/rma.php?l=en&amp;noclient=73742&amp;keepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=350&amp;width=475" title="RMA" class="thickbox">
                              RMA              </a></td>

              <td width="96" align="center" class="menu_principal">                  <a style="" href="contact-en.html">Contact Us</a> </td>
            </tr>


          </tbody></table>

        </div> 


















            <table width="100%" height="1000" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
              <tbody><tr>
              <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="texte" valign="top"><br>












          <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody><tr>
              <td width="120">



              <table height="36" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/topbutton/img_fond_titre.jpg">
                <tbody><tr>
                  <td valign="middle" class="titre"><img src="http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/topbutton/img_cote_gauche_titre.jpg" width="12" height="39"></td>
                  <td valign="top" class="titre"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tbody><tr>
                        <td height="5"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>

                        Order                        
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody></table></td>
                  <td width="16" align="right" valign="middle"><img src="http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/topbutton/img_cote_droit_titre.jpg" width="12" height="39"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody></table>


            </td>


              <td>&nbsp;











              </td>





            </tr>
          </tbody></table>






<br>




<table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4"><tbody><tr><td>
















<div class="dialog"> <div class="boxContent"> <div class="t"></div> 






<a style="color:#FFFFFF" href="/?ordernow=y&amp;rem=all">Delete All Products</a>



&nbsp;



</div> <div class="b"> <div> </div> </div> </div> 
















<div class="dialog"> <div class="boxContent"> <div class="t"></div> 






<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bordercolor="#FFD700" width="100%"><tbody><tr valign="top"><td valign="top">  

 &nbsp;&nbsp;<br><table class="tablemasterbleue" style="font-size:11px;" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody><tr class="headerlist">
        <td width="100" align="center">Prod #</td>
        <td width="100" align="center">Manufacturer</td>
        <td width="75" align="center">Qty</td>
        <td width="35"></td>
        <td width="35"></td>
        <td width="">Description</td>
        <td width="35"></td>
        <td width="100" align="center">Price</td>
    </tr>


        <tr style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; color:#000000; height:40px;" bgcolor="#EDEDED">
            <td align="left" width="125">&nbsp; <a href="/?ordernow=y&amp;rem=order&amp;prod=1"><img src="http://www.provincialtire.net/images/redcross.png"></a> &nbsp; 00959</td>
            <td align="center"><img title="" width="75" height="27" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/plugins/logo/UNIR.gif"></td>
            <td align="center"> 4 </td>
            <td align="left">-</td><td> <img width="30" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/plugins/type/W.png"> </td>
                <td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;205/60R16 Tiger Paw Ice &amp; Snow 3 </td>
            <td align="right"><div id="each1"><b></b></div></td><td style="background-image:url(/images/special.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top" align="center"><b>95.00</b></td>
    </tr><tr class="headerlist"><td colspan="8">

        <table width="100%" style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;" border="0">
            <tbody><tr style="color:#FFFFFF">
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="50">HST</td>
                <td width="25">

                <div id="tps">

                49.4                
                </div>



                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:#FFFFFF">
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="50"></td>
                <td width="25">


                <div id="tvq">





                </div>


                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:#FFFFFF">
                <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="50">TOTAL</td>
                <td width="25">
                    <div id="total">
                        429.4                
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

    </td></tr>

</tbody></table>






</td></tr></tbody></table>


<br><br>






</div> <div class="b"> <div> </div> </div> </div> 

</td></tr>

<tr><td>


</td></tr>

<tr><td>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="/sendorder-en.html">

<div class="dialog"> <div class="boxContent"> <div class="t"></div>  


 <table style="color:#FFFFFF" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="5">


          <tbody><tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">




              <br><b>This order does not apply to a national account<b><br><input type="hidden" value="n" name="clinat" id="clinat">       






               </b></b></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="50%"><b>Delivery Instruction: </b></td>
              <td width="50%"><input type="hidden" value="y" name="basketsend" id="basketsend"><input type="hidden" value="y" name="type" id="type"></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td rowspan="3" align="left" valign="top"><label>
                <input name="instruction" type="text" id="instruction" value="" maxlength="68" size="50">
              </label></td>
            <td align="right">



    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0">
      <tbody><tr>
         <td align="right">
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio1" checked="checked">Next delivery 
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio2">Morning 
            <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio3">Afternoon    
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
         <td align="right">   
             <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio4">Tomorrow Morning                
             <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio5">Tomorrow Afternoon   
          </td>
          </tr><tr>
          <td align="right">   
             <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio8">Standard Delivery                   
             <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio9">Urgent delivery  
          </td>
          </tr><tr> 
          <td align="right">   
             <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio6">Pick Up                 
              <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio7">See Special Instruction   
          </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody></table>            



    </td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">Purchase Order : 
                <label>
                  <input type="text" name="boncom" id="boncom" maxlength="10">
              </label></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="right"><input class="normal" width="300px" type="submit" name="buttonsend" id="buttonsend" value="Send" onclick="javascript:this.disabled=true;form1.submit();"></td>
              </tr>
        </tbody></table>
</div> <div class="b"> <div> </div> </div> </div>  </form>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
<br>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
/*$('a#first').imgPreview();*/
$('a#first').imgPreview({
    imgCSS: { width: 250 }
}); });

</script>                <br></td>
              <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
            <table width="960" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tablemasterbleueborder" border="3">

              <tbody><tr>
                <td height="36" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#ffffff">

                <table width="100%">
                  <tbody><tr>
                    <td align="center">
                    <a href="http://www.inosoft.ca/english/index.htm"> <img src="images/inosoft-en.jpg" width="125" height="35" alt="InoSoft"> </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody></table>
                </td>
              </tr>
          </tbody></table></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody></table>
      <br>
      <center>
      <a href="exit-en.html" style="color:#000">Exit</a>
      </center>
    <br></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<div id="imgPreviewContainer" style="display: none;"><img style="width: 250px;"></div></body></html>
```

Here is also screenshot of inspect element : https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcEar.png
[image]

So I'm going to use the xpath or do I need another solution?

thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the page you're scraping use Javascript or is the HTML ready to parse? Please reduce your XPath expression and your HTML to something postable and post that. Without seeing the HTML (and [mcve]), we can't reproduce your situation and then we can not really help you.

Comment: the page use HTML

Comment: <td align="left" width="125">&nbsp; <a href="/?ordernow=y&amp;rem=order&amp;prod=1"><img src="http://www.provincialtire.net/images/redcross.png"></a> &nbsp; 00959</td>

Comment: Please edit your question and add the additional data there.

Comment: i want to add screenshots but they dosen't allow.

Comment: Don't add screenshots when you can add text.

Comment: Oky done I add the code HTML in Answer.

Comment: And I upload my screenshot so you can see it in this path : https://i.imgur.com/o59X5wA.png

Comment: Please don't add information in answers. Add the information by editing your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem is that *XPath* queries like `//tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[5]/span` returns *null*, because there is no corresponding `span` HTML element and so `.InnerText` crashes with `NullReferenceException`. Also indexes of `td` elements (like `td[5]`) seems to be wrong. Correct *XPath* is `//tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[6]`. But you can rewrite your code to make it much better.

Because you want to iterate through multiple product nodes, it is better to use `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes()` that returns collection of all matching nodes (products) instead of `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode()`. Each selected product node looks similar to this:

```
<tr style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px; color:#000000; height:40px;" bgcolor="#EDEDED">
    <td align="left" width="125">&nbsp; <a href="/?ordernow=y&amp;rem=order&amp;prod=1"><img src="http://www.provincialtire.net/images/redcross.png"></a> &nbsp; 00959</td>
    <td align="center"><img title="" width="75" height="27" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/plugins/logo/UNIR.gif"></td>
    <td align="center"> 4 </td>
    <td align="left">-</td><td> <img width="30" src="http://www.provincialtire.net/provt/images/plugins/type/W.png"> </td>
    <td align="left">&nbsp;&nbsp;205/60R16 Tiger Paw Ice &amp; Snow 3 </td>
    <td align="right"><div id="each1"><b></b></div></td><td style="background-image:url(/images/special.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top" align="center"><b>95.00</b></td>
</tr>
```

With this node already selected, you don't need to execute whole complicated *XPath* query like `/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[1]` again to gather desired pieces of information. Execute *XPath* query only agains HTML node selected above, e.g. `node.SelectSingleNode("td[1]")`, which is not only much shorter and readable, but also more efficient. Whole code may look like this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tablemasterbleue").InnerHtml);

foreach(var node in doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr")
    .Skip(1)/*Skip first row containing headers*/)
{
    string Code_de_ligne = "";
    string Numero_de_produit = node.SelectSingleNode("td[1]").InnerText;
    string Desc_prod = node.SelectSingleNode("td[6]").InnerText;
    string Prix_coutânt = node.SelectSingleNode("td[8]").InnerText;
    string Prix_de_vente = "";
    string Qte = node.SelectSingleNode("td[3]").InnerText;

    MessageBox.Show(Code_de_ligne + "|" + Numero_de_produit + "|" + Desc_prod + " | " + Prix_coutânt + "|" + Prix_de_vente + "|" + Qte);
}
```

Because obtained strings may contain excessive HTML entities and spaces like "`&nbsp;  &nbsp; 00959`", you may need to remove them:

```
// Convert string like "&nbsp;  &nbsp; 00959" to just "00959"
Numero_de_produit = HtmlEntity.DeEntitize(Numero_de_produit).Trim();
```

Comment: Your code it's very practical and I will use it thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: Hello I just wanna ask you when I execute my code in foreach line it gives me this message error : System.ArgumentNullException: 'La valeur ne peut pas être null.
Nom du paramètre : source'

Comment: Hello I just wanna ask you when I execute my code in foreach line it gives me this message error : 
System.ArgumentNullException: 'The value can not be null. Parameter name: source'

Comment: This means that there is no HTML element that matches requested XPath `/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr`. In HTML document you provided there are 3 matching nodes, but if you tried with another HTML document, there can be no such element and in that case `SelectNodes()` returns *null*. If you cannot guarantee that at least 1 matching HTML element exists, you'll need to add null-check to deal with such condition.

Answer (score 0):

`tablemasterbleue` is a `class` not `id` and because no method `GetElementsByClassName` extract get page source with `WebBrowser1.DocumentText` then loop rows or `tr`.

the following xpath will select rows in table class `tablemasterbleue` but skip if has class `headerlist` which exist in the top and bottom.

```
doc.LoadHtml(WebBrowser1.DocumentText);

foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//table[@class='tablemasterbleue']/tbody/tr[not(contains(@class, 'headerlist'))]"))
{
    string Code_de_ligne = "";
    string Numero_de_produit = node.SelectSingleNode("td[1]").InnerText;
    string Desc_prod = node.SelectSingleNode("td[6]").InnerText;
    string Prix_coutânt = node.SelectSingleNode("td[8]").InnerText;
    string Prix_de_vente = "";
    string Qte = node.SelectSingleNode("td[3]").InnerText;

    MessageBox.Show(Code_de_ligne + "|" + Numero_de_produit + "|" + Desc_prod + " | " + Prix_coutânt + "|" + Prix_de_vente + "|" + Qte);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me, it still the same error    
System.ArgumentNullException: 'The value can not be null. Parameter name: source'

Comment: do you now what variable that null?

Comment: Yes source parameter I think.